# FPDF MultiCell Automatic Row Height

Tags: php, fpdf

This is how my table looks right now.

[image]

You guys can clearly see that some of the texts overflows and the rows have different height. What I want is to have each row the **same height**. Like for example, if the *`IMPACTS`* have the longest data then the height of the *SS Height, Provinces, Low Lying and Advice* should be have same height as the *IMPACTS*. Same with the 2nd row and to what follows.

Can you guys help me on how to do it? Thank you. Here's my whole code.

```
<?php

require("con.php")

$sql="SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ssh REGEXP '^[^A-Za-z0-9]' ASC, ssh DESC";

$records=mysqli_query($sql);
$fetch = $records;

require("library/fpdf.php");

$pdf = new PDF('p', 'mm', 'Legal');
$title = 'Storm Surge Warning';
$pdf->SetTitle($title);
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{pages}');
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,40);

$pdf->AddPage();

$chartX=10;
$chartY=34;

$chartWidth=194;
$chartHeight=18;

$chartTopPadding=10;
$chartLeftPadding=20;
$chartBottomPadding=20;
$chartRightPadding=5;

$chartBoxX=$chartX+$chartLeftPadding;
$chartBoxY=$chartY+$chartTopPadding;
$chartBoxWidth=$chartWidth-$chartLeftPadding-$chartRightPadding;
$chartBoxHeight=$chartHeight-$chartTopPadding-$chartBottomPadding;

$pdf->Rect($chartX, $chartY, $chartWidth,     $chartHeight);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);

$pdf->MultiCell(194,4,"STORM SURGE INFORMATION",0,'C', false);
$pdf->MultiCell(194,4, "STORM SURGE: WARNING # " .    $fetch['warning'], 0,'C', false);
$pdf->MultiCell(194,4,"FOR: TYPHOON " . $fetch['typhoon'], 0,'C', false);
$pdf->MultiCell(194,4,"ISSUED AT " . $fetch['date'], 0,'C', false);
$pdf->Ln(1);

$pdf->SetBorders(array('LT', 'LT', 'LT', 'LT', 'TLR'));
$pdf->SetWidths(array(25, 27, 35, 54, 53));
$pdf->SetAligns(array('C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'));

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);

$x = 70; 
$y = 50;

$pdf->Row(array("SS Height",
            "Provinces",
            "Low Lying Coastal Areas in the Municipalities of:",
            "IMPACTS",
            "ADVICE/Actions to Take"), 1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 11);

$pdf->SetAligns(array('C', 'C', 'C', 'L', 'L'));

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)){

  $x = $pdf->GetX(); 
  $y = $pdf->GetY();

 switch ($row['ssh']) { 
    case '2-3Meters' : 
    $pdf->SetFillColor(191, 143, 0); 
    $pdf->Cell(25, 75, $row['ssh'], 1, 0, 'C', TRUE); 
    break; 
    case  '1-2Meters' : 
    $pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 0); 
    $pdf->Cell(25, 50, $row['ssh'], 1, 0, 'C', TRUE); 
    break; 
    case '<1Meter' : 
    $pdf->SetFillColor(91, 155, 213);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 55, $row['ssh'], 1, 0, 'C', TRUE); 
    break; 

    default : 
    $pdf->Cell(25, 10, $row['ssh'], 1, 1, 'C', FALSE); 
    break; 
    }

  $pdf->MultiCell(27,4,$row['provi'],1,'C'); 

  $pdf->SetXY($x + 52, $y); 
  $pdf->Multicell(35,4,$row['muni'],1,'C');

  $pdf->SetXY($x + 87, $y); 
  $pdf->Multicell(54,4,$row['impact'],1,'C');

  $pdf->SetXY($x + 141, $y); 
  $pdf->Multicell(53,4,$row['advice'],1,'C'); 
}

$pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
$pdf->OutPut();
?>
```